# Invertir datos de dos usuarios

Tags: python

¿Existe alguna forma en **Python** de cambiar los nombres ingresados por dos usuarios?
Me explico con un ejemplo:

```
def player(player1, player2):
    for turno in range(1,3):
        vidas=6
        while vidas>0:
             #juego
```

Cuando el juego termina sale del ciclo `while` y entra de nuevo al ciclo `for` pero player1 y player2 siguen con los mismos nombres.

¿Se podría invertir los nombres de los jugadores?.

Sin tener que hacer otra función o que vuelvan a escribir sus nombres de nuevo.

Comment: Bienvenido @KevinBaez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Sí es posible @KevinBaez, si se tiene `player1 = "A"` y `player2 = "B"` sólo hay que escribir lo siguiente: `player1, player2 = player2, player1` luego se puede verificar con `print(player1, player2)` se imprime `B A` si estás en **python3**, pero si fuera **python2** se imprime `('B', 'A')` en ese caso sólo poner `print player1, player2`

Comment: ¡¡¡Funciona, muchas gracias!!! @HubertRonald